# Asymptotic distribution of multiplicities when selecting $k$ integers from $[1,n]$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, asymptotics

When selecting $k$ integers from $[1,n]$ uniformly and with replacement, what does the distribution of multiplicities look like? For example, on average how many numbers will be selected exactly $m$ times? And what is the standard deviation?

Instead of an exact answer, I would like to consider where $k$ is a fraction of $n$, and discussing the asymptotics of the results as $n$ increases. So if we write $k=cn$ for some constant $0<c$, then I shall denote the distribution $f(c,m)$ as the expected fraction of the values selected exactly $m$ times. I am also interested in the standard deviation from this expected value.

I've tried some numerical tests with $k=n=10000000$, and then at least up to m=6 the distribution appears to follow:

$$ f(1,m) = \frac{1}{e\ m!}$$

And the fluctuations from these averages appear quite small.  I'm really hoping there is a nice closed form solution for these distributions.

Comment: it could depend on a weighted version of the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Your $f(0) = f(1) \dots$ line does not make sense. Can you correct it?

Comment: @Aryabhata I wrote a quick test in python to check, and got the same thing. When k=n it looks pretty close to f(m) = constant/m! (Additionally, it looks like this constant = 1/e, which makes sense for the sum to equal one.) So unless I made a similar error, it looks fine to me.

Comment: @BuddyJohn: Ok. Looks like I didn't understand and got confused. Thanks for the explanation. To be fair (to myself :-P) why not just write $f(m) = A/m!$ for some constant $A$, instead of the convoluted $f(0) = f(1)  = f(2) 2 \dots$. Writing $f(2) 2$ instead of $2f(2)$ made me thing there were some terms missing.

Comment: @Aryabhata I could only see out a few numbers based on the numerical data, and even then I was unsure how much I was just seeing a rough trend instead of a formula. Maybe I could have worded it better. I'll try to edit the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of values that occur exactly $m$ times can be written as the sum of indicator random variables.
Letting $U_i:={\bf 1}_{[\text{value } i \text{ occurs }m\text{ times}]}$ we have 
$N_m=\sum_{i=1}^n U_i$. Using the binomial distribution,
 we calculate $$\mathbb{E}(U_i)=\mathbb{P}(\text{value } i \text{ occurs }m\text{ times})
={k\choose m}\left({1\over n}\right)^m\left(1-{1\over n}\right)^{k-m},\tag1$$
so that $$\mathbb{E}(N_m)=n{k\choose m}\left({1\over n}\right)^m\left(1-{1\over n}\right)^{k-m}.$$ 
If you set $k=cn$ and let $n\to\infty$ in (1) you find that $\mathbb{E}(N_m/n)\to {c^m\over m!}\, e^{-c}.$

---

The random variables $U_i$ are exchangeable so that 
$$\mbox{Var}(N_m)=\sum_{i,j}\mbox{Cov}(U_i,U_j)=n\mbox{Var}(U_1)+n(n-1)\mbox{Cov}(U_1,U_2),$$ and thus
$$n\mbox{Var}(N_m/n)=\mbox{Var}(U_1)+(n-1)\mbox{Cov}(U_1,U_2).\tag2$$
The limit of the right hand side of (2) as $n\to\infty$ is the coefficient of $n^{-1}$ in the asymptotic expansion of $\mbox{Var}(N_m/n).$

The first term is easy. Defining $p={c^m\over m!}\, e^{-c}$, we have
$$\mbox{Var}(U_1)=\mathbb{E}(U_1)-\mathbb{E}(U_1)^2\to p-p^2. $$

The second term is a bit more complicated. 
Using the multinomial distribution we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Cov}(U_1,U_2)&=&\mathbb{E}(U_1U_2)-\mathbb{E}(U_1)\mathbb{E}(U_2)\\[8pt]
&=&{k\choose m, m, k-2m}\left({1\over n}\right)^m\left({1\over n}\right)^m\left(1-{1\over n}\right)^{k-2m}-\left[{k\choose m}\left({1\over n}\right)^m\left(1-{1\over n}\right)^{k-m}\right]^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiplying by $n-1$ and taking the limit gives 
$$(n-1)\mbox{Cov}(U_1,U_2)\to p^2(m^2c+2m-c),$$
so that the desired coefficient is $p+p^2(m^2c+2m-c-1).$

Comment: Can you comment on the standard deviation? For an individual number, I'd expect the counts to be Poisson like, but once we look over all the numbers for any to have occurred m times, is the standard deviation still roughly sqrt(mean) ?

Comment: @JJMalone I'm not sure I understand your comment, but with calculations like those in my answer you can show that the variance of $N_m/n$ goes to  zero as $n\to\infty.$

Comment: Yes, it would go to zero, but what is the leading term asymptotically? If the asymptotic expectation is $N_m = n c^m e^{-c} / m!$, and it is roughly Poisson like (not sure if that is justified), then the standard deviation goes like $N_m = \sqrt{n c^m e^{-c} / m!}$ ... in other words the standard deviation of $N_m/n$ goes like $1/\sqrt{n}$ (if it is Poisson like).

Comment: I'm confused. The number of occurrences is "Poisson-like" in the variable $m$ for a fixed value. In my result the value $m$ is fixed, and we average over all values, then let $n\to\infty$. These are two totally different problems, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I don't know if it is "Poisson-like", I just gave an example to show what I mean even if the standard deviation goes to zero as $n \to \infty$. I'd like to know the leading term of the asymptotic expansion just as you did for the mean.

Comment: OK, I'm working on it.